# Same Route53 DNS Entry to two load balancers using different ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I have a use case where I want to use an application load balancer for HTTPS 443 requests and also a network load balancer for TCP 9467 peering requests. they both point to different target groups which point to the same ec2 instance.

I need to have both of the load balancers behind the same dns name such as foo.bar.com is this possible in route 53? And if so how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want same dns name but depending on which port is used in the incoming request, the traffic should be routed to either ALB or NLB ?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: In that case you need to use a reverse proxy like nginx